# Bootstrap dropdown menu fails

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, menu, dropdown

Im new using bootstrap and Im having two  big problems:

**1. Im trying to include a dropdown section in the menu but it doesnt work at all.**

**2. When the screen is small it shows the button menu but it doesnt work too.**

This is the code that I rescued from a website so it supposed to work perfectly, I dont know if it is a library mistake or that im doing the rows and cols wrong:

```
<div class="row menu" >
          <header class="barra">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input id="buscar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason is that you might be missing the functionality coming from JavaScript Bootstrap modules.

Try to add JS imports:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I do have the JS imports so that is not the problem :(  Now it "works" but the div below it cover it so its hidden behind it..